# Laravel 5.2 uploading file using filesystem

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

I am having some troubles with laravels filesystem uploading.

When I try to execute this code

```
Storage::disk('public')->put(
            $img->getClientOriginalName(),
            file_get_contents($img->getRealPath())
        );
```

nothing happens locally in the public folder, I even checked if the file exists and it returns true

```
dd(Storage::disk('public')->exists($img->getClientOriginalName()));
```

For now I am using the `$img->move` method and it works as I want to.

Disk is also configured in filesystems.php

```
 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I am confused with this because a couple of weeks ago it worked as it should on another project.

Comment: If you want to upload files in /public folder write  `'root' => public_path('')`

Comment: In your example, could you please show how you define $img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now fixed this problem with the help of Claudio by using `'root' => public_path('')`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if ($request->hasFile('myFile'))
{
    $fileExtension = strtolower($request->file('myFile')->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $newFilename = str_random(20) . '.' . $fileExtension;
    $storagePath = storage_path() . '/app/uploads/';
    $request->file('myFile')->move($storagePath, $newFilename);
}
```

Comment: This is the solution am I using currently and it works fine, but I want to use the filesystems feature which doesn't actually store files on the local disk. The file does appear on the disk if I check for its existence or even if I get it.